# Can't play UDF DVD burned in Windows 7. Error mounting

Tags: dvd, udf

I am trying to play a DVD on my system, it was burned in Windows 7 and given to me.
I was told that the file system used was .mp4
I get this error:

```
Unable to mount UDF Volume

Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/ben/UDF Volume: Command-line `mount -t "udf" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077" "/dev/sr0" "/media/ben/UDF Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

I have installed udf package

```
sudo apt-get install libudf0
```

according to a forum post relevant to karmic but that made no difference.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you on? Can you mount it from the file manager? Try not specifying the filesystem. ie. mount /dev/sr0 /mnt. MP4 is not a filesystem, it is a media container format.

Comment: I am on 14.04. "Can you mount it from the file manager?"  If I go to places>computer it is listed as udf volume but it won't mount there either.

Comment: Sorry, it was burned in Windows 8, not 7. " Try not specifying the filesystem. ie. mount /dev/sr0 /mnt. "   I get mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock. BTW how to do a new line within the text without pressing "enter" (which submits the text as it is)?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /mnt`

You may also wish to install Ubuntu-restricted-addons to obtain the codes required to play an .mp4 These are available through the software center.

[image]

Comment: I got : special device /dev/dvd does not exist. In the software centre I already have the restricted packages.

Comment: My mistake. corrected answer.

Comment: Now I get: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you would like to burn the video onto the disc so that you can play it through a DVD player, ie: the disc's format is similar to that of a film. For that, you can't just burn the file onto a disc.You need a DVD authoring tool, such as the free cross-platform (not to mention open-source) DVD Styler (http://www.dvdstyler.org/). And hatterman is right, MP4 is a file format, not a filesystem. However, if the file burned to the new disc was a disc image of the previous disc, I don't see an immediate problem.Try another disc with the same on it - sometimes it can just be a slight defect with the disc.

Comment: No, my friend gave me the DVD that he had burned from his video camera via his windows 8 pc. It is a data DVD with just .mp4 files on it. I only have XP (with the .mp4 codec)  and Ubuntu and can't play it on either. I don't mind if I can play it on a DVD player or not. I want to play it on my pc so I can edit it. So I am somewhat restricted in what I can do to eliminate possible causes of the problem. I will have access to a Windows 7 pc at the weekend and will try it on that. I don't even know if I have a known worker yet. He says it played on his spare windows 7 pc.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about "burn" burn, because that overwrites everything on the disk. Give it ago in Windows though.

Comment: Sounds to me like a defective disc. Ask your friend to burn another copy.